# Min-Height 100%?

Tags: css, xhtml, size

I want to be able to have a container element which contains the content to repeat and expand as the content goes on, but the container per se is in between two elements in which give heed of the container element "stopping" at some point.

You may view the design at:

http://www.noxinnovations.com/portfolio/charidimos/

What I want to do is have the container element which contains the content to be set at 100%. So no matter what it will always be correct in size without a set size.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as you give the body a `height:100%`, you can give your container a `min-height:100%` and it will stretch. Without it's parent having a height (the body, in this case) it won't stretch.

Comment: It does not stretch. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You must have some serious resetters in there :) add `height:100%;` to the html as well: `html {height:100%;}`

Comment: Okay now that works. The only problem is, is that it stretches it too much, and I have to scroll down the page to see the footer. No what I am saying? lol. and yes I do have some serious master resets chugging away here lol. Thank you again.

Comment: Hmm in that case I'd recommend adding `overflow:hidden;` to your body css, and then adding `overflow:auto; height:100%;` to your nested divs - that should keep the wrapper inside the initial viewport and force your divs with the excess content to do the scrolling.