# Min-height: 100% is not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a div that will expand to 100% of the screen height when there is not enough content for it to do so normally, but will expand normally beyond that if there is enough content. If my div is called container, then whenever I use

```
#container
{
min-height: 100%;
}
```

it seems to have no affect on the height at all. When I use

```
#container
{
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
}
```

it sets the height to a fixed 100%, cutting off any content that would normally be past 100% of the screen height. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: http://unnaturalcode.blogspot.com/2012/08/css-recipe-for-making-elements-fill.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Borrowed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737790/min-height-100). You can also [refer this](http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/examples/csslayout1.html).

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bq8mm/)

Comment: This has the same affect as when I set the div's height to 100%. It cuts off anything that would normally be beyond the users screen, and theres no scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe could you give us a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.com) of your HTML ? It would help us helping you.

I think you could use:

```
#container
{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Or play around with position/float/clear.